# Crash on builder.create()

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to figure this one out really. I'm trying to make a simple `AlertDialog`, but every time I execute the code it crashes at the `.create()` part.

Here's the code:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Unit:")
            .setItems(units, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    unitIndex = i;
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

It is in a void function if that matters (As it supposed to be executed from an onclick event)

Thanks!

EDIT (LOGCAT):

```
[ 07-24 17:10:10.291 10948:11095 W/         ]

Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
07-24 17:10:13.019 10948-10948/com.example.alexanderfehr.speedo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alexanderfehr.speedo, PID: 10948
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
t android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2094)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertController.java:966)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.java:942)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:930)
at com.example.alexanderfehr.speedo.MainActivity.setUnit(MainActivity.java:188)
at com.example.alexanderfehr.speedo.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:27)
at com.example.alexanderfehr.speedo.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I'm kinda new to using logcat, and it seems that there's to little info here, so if somebody knows what I'm supposed to do to get the full error please let me know, and sorry :I

Comment: if it crashes please post the stack trace

Comment: look at logcat and set Error scope.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm kinda new to using android studio so if I messed up the log please let me know how to correct it...

Comment: What type of variable is "units" in 'setItems'?

Comment: String[], and I'm starting to think that's the problem. You're supposed to use a xml string-array right? In that case, how do you link it the xml file to the java?

Comment: The developer page shows that this one should be an Array. The type specified in the developer site is 'CharSequence[]'. Or you can use an 'array.xml' file and call it in the java file like: 'R.array.your_array'

Comment: Tried both using a charsequence[] and xml, but still the same crash. I used breakpoints and found out that the crash dosen't happen on this part of the code but rather on the .create() section, this dosen't of course mean that this section is correct...

Comment: try my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps explicitly setting a theme would help.

Put this in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert" />
```

And create your AlertDialog.Builder with it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,  R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

Comment: Oh wow, that actually works. I guess that Material.Light.NoActionBar dosen't have support for alertdialogs and therefore it fails? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, there should be a default one shipped with the SDK. If it doesn't, you can add it like the way describes here.

http://alexzh.com/tutorials/material-style-for-dialogs-in-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

The setItems method is taking and `itemId` for the first argument. As I can see, you're passing `units` as a first argument. Check if `units` is a valid `itemId`.

Also, your construct may be changed to something like:

```
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
```

See that there is no `setItems` in this construction... No itemId to send.

Comment: After reading in the docs it seems that I've messed up with the data type, but after switching it out to a xml string-array and linking that instead it still crashes the same way...

Comment: `setItem` also takes `CharSequence[] items` as first argument. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems(java.lang.CharSequence[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

Answer (score 0):

I created and tested this method:

```
public void createDialog() {

        CharSequence[] example = {"one", "two"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                .setItems(example, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                        // of the selected item
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You choose: " + which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();

    }
```

and it works fine. Try to use it and let me know. Try to call this method for example in the `onClick` of a `Fab` like `createDialog()`.

Comment: Weird, still doesn't work on the emulator nor my phone. EDIT: Okay, I tried it out in a new project and it works, so this is getting weirder and weirder...

Comment: So the problem is not the AlertDialog then. Is the app crashing when you press the button where you call the method or in the 'onCreate()' when you launch the app?

Comment: if you can post all the code in the MainActivity I could see where the error is

Comment: Solved it, seems that the theme was the problem, changed it back to stock and now it works. Hopefully that's just a bug that will be fixed...